# Passing ImageData from One View Controller to Another

Tags: swift, imageview, uistoryboardsegue, forced-unwrapping, imagedata

Hello I have ran into this situation before. I have image data that I want to pass from one view controller to another and display that data in an image view. In viewdidload in the 2nd VC, the data is printed properly but when I try to insert that data into 2nd VC imageview, the imageview is blank. You can see from the output that the printing the image data returns nil.

```
import UIKit

class ImageSelectedViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var imageViewData = Data()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(imageViewData)
    imageView.image? = UIImage(data: imageViewData)!
    print(imageView.image?.pngData())
}
```

Console:

205,397 bytes

nil

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageViewData)!
```

as `?` here `imageView.image?` can make the whole line not effective